# como averiguar que llamadas hace el codigo JavaScript

Tags: javascript

quisiera saber como se podria buscar las llamadas que hace el codigo de JavaScript en una pagina web

muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Abre las Herramientas de Desarrollo de tu navegador (generalmente puedes hacerlo pulsando F12), seguramente encontrarás una pestaña "Red" o "Network" donde podrás ver todas las peticiones realizadas por el navegador:

[image: Herramientas de Desarrollo de Chrome]

Comment: y como se cual de ellos es la llamada? o son todas?

Comment: Todos son llamadas. En el caso de la imagen la primera columna es la url, la segunda es el método utilizado, la 3ª el código de respuesta del servidor, la 4ª el tipo de contenido... Pulsando sobre cualquiera de ellas accedes al detalle, tanto de la petición como de la respuesta.

Comment: vale vale ahora entiendo algo mas! muchas gracias!